# How to resolve Type 'Observable<string>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<{ userId: string; partyId: string; }>'

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

In my angular project I have written following piece of code, but somehow the complier not happy with it, however, I couldnt able to find where exactly I made the mistake in the code:

```
    public getUser(): Observable<{ userId: string; partyId: string }> {
    return this.userRepository.getLoggedInUser().pipe(
        map((user: User) => {
            const partyId = user.getUniqueClaimValue(this.claimTypesService.partyId);
            this.persistPartyUserClaims(partyId);
            return { userId: user.Id, partyId: partyId };
        }),
        catchError((err) => throwError(() => err)),
        concatMap(({ partyId }) => this.persistPartyUserClaims$(partyId))
    );
}
```

and the persistPartyUserClaims$ method is below:

```
    public persistPartyUserClaims$(partyId: string): Observable<string> {
    return this.storageMap.set('partyId', partyId, { type: 'string' }).pipe(concatMap(() => of(partyId)));
}
```

So I have realized that the line `concatMap(({ partyId }) => this.persistPartyUserClaims$(partyId))` inside getUser() method is causing the issue, as soon as I remove the line from the method its works fine. Below I have attached a screenshot of the errors throwing from compiler:

[image]

How can I make this getUser() method working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `getUser` method is suppose to return `Observable<{ userId: string; partyId: string }>` but your `persistPartyUserClaims$` is returning `Observable<string>` which is called inside `concatMap`.So you can try returning  the `Observable<{ userId: string; partyId: string }>` from your `persistPartyUserClaims$` method so your code will look like

```
public getUser(): Observable<{ userId: string; partyId: string }> {
    return this.userRepository.getLoggedInUser().pipe(
        map((user: User) => {
            const partyId = user.getUniqueClaimValue(this.claimTypesService.partyId);
            this.persistPartyUserClaims(partyId);
            return { userId: user.Id, partyId: partyId };
        }),
        catchError((err) => throwError(() => err)),
        concatMap((res) => this.persistPartyUserClaims$(res))
    );
}

public persistPartyUserClaims$(res:{ userId: string; partyId: string }): Observable<{ userId: string; partyId: string }> {
    return this.storageMap.set('partyId', res.partyId, { type: 'string' }).pipe(concatMap(() => of(res)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to convert the return type as `unknown` then `Observable<{ userId: string; partyId: string }>`

```
public getUser(): Observable<{ userId: string; partyId: string }> {
    return this.userRepository.getLoggedInUser().pipe(
        map((user: User) => {
            const partyId = user.getUniqueClaimValue(this.claimTypesService.partyId);
            this.persistPartyUserClaims(partyId);
            return { userId: user.Id, partyId: partyId };
        }),
        catchError((err) => throwError(() => err)),
        concatMap(({ partyId }) => this.persistPartyUserClaims$(partyId))
    ) as unknown as Observable<{ userId: string; partyId: string }>;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Please try this you need to return Observable<{ userId: string; partyId: string }> from your function.

```
public getUser(): Observable<{ userId: string; partyId: string }> {
    return this.userRepository.getLoggedInUser().pipe(
        map((user: User) => {
            const partyId = user.getUniqueClaimValue(this.claimTypesService.partyId);
            this.persistPartyUserClaims(partyId);
            return { userId: user.Id, partyId: partyId };
        }),
        catchError((err) => throwError(() => err)), 
       //write your logic here to return Observable<{ userId: string; partyId: string }>
        concatMap(() =>{ partyId= this.persistPartyUserClaims$(partyId); return{ userId: null, partyId: partyId }})
       
    );
}
```

Comment: it's all async so that's not gonna work, besides it's not even valid to write return statement after that concatMap function.

Comment: This is syntactically wrong and misleading.